# Problema con expresión regular en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tengo un texto y quiero seleccionar cada articulo por separado (desde el inicio de la fila hasta que coincida con el número con decimales y con el salto de línea (que cuando son varias unidades está en dos filas)

```
import re
patron = re.compile (r "[A-Z].*\d{0,3},\d\d\n") 
salida = patrón.findall (texto)
```

Pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar ¿Qué hago mal?

```
ACEITE OLIVA 750ML                3,59
BIPACK KAS LIMÓN      A260
    2 x (     2,10 )              4,20
BIPACK KAS NARANJA    A260
    4 x (     2,25 )              9,00
CAVA CASTELL LLAC                 2,50
FAIRY REGULAR 1,5L    A227
    2 x (     4,58 )              9,16
AGUJA CABO PEÑAS                  1,77
GALLETA MARIA DORADA
    2 x (     0,99 )              1,98
NUEZ MONDADA CARRE                2,26
CHORIZO DULCE CARR                1,99
MORCILLA DE ARROZ                 1,39
OBLEAS EMPANADILLA    2C55
    3 x (     0,89 )              2,67
YOGUR NATURAL 8 X125  3H80        0,90
QUESO RESERVA 1/8                 3,48
ALMEJA MARINERA 500G  C138        7,99
ALMEJA MARINERA 500G  C138        7,99
```

Comment: El nombre del producto puede llevar valores decimales (1,5L) y puede no llevar precio en la misma línea. Como el formato de los datos parecen tener una estructura fija, es más simple, fácil y seguro procesar cada línea con rebanado de listas.

Answer (score 0):

Es más simple usar rebanado de listas, dado que el formato es fijo:

- El nombre viene en los primeros 26 caracteres.
- El precio viene a partir de la columna 27.

La línea puede traer el nombre y precio, sólo nombre o solo precio. En cualquier caso, imprimimos sólo cuando tenemos el precio

Con la información puesta en el archivo "boleta.txt", el código queda asi:

```
with open("boleta.txt", "r") as boleta:
    for linea in boleta:
        linea = linea.strip("\n")
        if linea[0] != ' ':
            nombre = linea[:26]
            precio = linea[26:].strip()
        else:
            precio = linea[26:].strip()

        if len(precio):
            print(f"{nombre}, precio {precio}")
```

produce:

```
ACEITE OLIVA 750ML        , precio 3,59
BIPACK KAS LIMÓN      A260, precio 4,20
BIPACK KAS NARANJA    A260, precio 9,00
CAVA CASTELL LLAC         , precio 2,50
FAIRY REGULAR 1,5L    A227, precio 9,16
AGUJA CABO PEÑAS          , precio 1,77
GALLETA MARIA DORADA, precio 1,98
NUEZ MONDADA CARRE        , precio 2,26
CHORIZO DULCE CARR        , precio 1,99
MORCILLA DE ARROZ         , precio 1,39
OBLEAS EMPANADILLA    2C55, precio 2,67
YOGUR NATURAL 8 X125  3H80, precio 0,90
QUESO RESERVA 1/8         , precio 3,48
ALMEJA MARINERA 500G  C138, precio 7,99
ALMEJA MARINERA 500G  C138, precio 7,99
```

Comment: Gracias por la idea Candid Moe, pero me parece mas rápido y con menos código con el modulo re , siempre que sea posible,  claro

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haces mal es que el patrón que tú buscas sólo encaja con las líneas que terminan con un precio. Las líneas que "continúan por la lína siguiente" no encajan, ya que en la parte del `.*` el `.` por defecto no admite un retorno de carro.

Por otro lado, si el `.` admitiera el retorno de carro (cosa que puedes forzar pasando el flag `re.S`), entonces la expresión, al ser voraz, "tragaría" el contenido completo del fichero, puesto que encajaría todo (incluyendo retornos de carro) hasta el precio final del último producto.

Para evitar que un grupo sea voraz debes poner un `?` tras el `*`. Eso indica que encaje "lo mínimo posible" (en vez de lo máximo posible).

Por otro lado, para poder acceder separadamente al nombre del producto y a su precio necesitas hacer grupos de captura. No me queda claro si quieres capturar también los códigos como "A260". Asumiré que no.

En ese caso, lo siguiente funciona:

```
patron = re.compile(r"^(.*?)(  +)(.*?)(\d,\d\d)\n?$", flags=re.M|re.S)
r = re.findall(patron, txt)
```

El resultado `r` es una lista de tuplas. Cada elemento de la tupla es un grupo de captura. La expresión ha usado cuatro grupos de captura:

- El primero tiene el nombre del producto
- El segundo tiene espacios que separan al nombre del precio o del código
- El tercero tiene todo lo que haya entre esos espacios y el precio final (incluyendo saltos de línea si los hubiera)
- El cuarto tiene el precio

Entiendo que sólo interesan el primero y el último. El siguiente bucle los imprime:

```
for result in r:
  print("{:35s}{}".format(result[0].strip(), result[-1]))
```

y el resultado es:

```
ACEITE OLIVA 750ML                 3,59
BIPACK KAS LIMÓN                   4,20
BIPACK KAS NARANJA                 9,00
CAVA CASTELL LLAC                  2,50
FAIRY REGULAR 1,5L                 9,16
AGUJA CABO PEÑAS                   1,77
GALLETA MARIA DORADA               1,98
NUEZ MONDADA CARRE                 2,26
CHORIZO DULCE CARR                 1,99
MORCILLA DE ARROZ                  1,39
OBLEAS EMPANADILLA                 2,67
YOGUR NATURAL 8 X125               0,90
QUESO RESERVA 1/8                  3,48
ALMEJA MARINERA 500G               7,99
ALMEJA MARINERA 500G               7,99
```

Debo decir no obstante que esta solución **no es más rápida** que aplicar *slices*. Las expresiones regulares no son necesariamente más rápidas, su velocidad depende de la complejidad de la expresión en sí.

En este caso he hecho unas pruebas y la solución de @CandidMoe tarda aproximadamente la mitad que la solución con expresiones regulares. Además, las expresiones regulares son difíciles de leer y de explicar, y por tanto de mantener, y menos flexibles.

Comment: El problema era la "voracidad" con esa limitación me funciona perfectamente:                                                                  
   patron=re.compile( r"[A-Z]*.*?\n?.*\d,\d\d\n")   Muchas gracias abulafia

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto otra solución. Acá usamos la función `findall()` del módulo `re`, y le pasaremos como argumento el siguiente patrón:

```
(\w+(?:\s{1}\w+)*)[\s\S]+?(\d+\,\d{2})\n
```

Decomponiendo el patrón, tenemos los siguientes elementos:

- Hay un primer grupo de captura que contiene:

  - `\w+`: Uno o más caracteres, que sean dígitos o letras.
  - `(?:\s{1}\w+)*`: Un único espacio en blanco, o una cadena de caracteres que sean dígitos o letras, opcionales.
- `[\s\S]+?`: Cualquier carácter, incluyendo saltos de líneas. Con el símbolo `?`, se le ordena que el match sea hecho de manera lazy. O sea, que tan pronto como se satisfaga el patrón, se prosiga con el siguiente.
- Hay un segundo grupo de captura que contiene:

  - `(\d+\,\d{2})`: Un dígito seguido por una coma, seguido por dos dígitos.
- `\n`: Todo lo anterior tiene que terminar en un salto de línea

Así, con el siguiente sencillo código, podemos obtener lo que deseamos. Personalmente me gusta bastante, `articles` contiene tuplas de dos posiciones que contiene el nombre del artículo en la primera, y el precio del mismo en la segunda. Esto hace que la información sea de bastante fácil acceso.

```
import re


with open('factura.txt') as file:
    content = file.read()

articles = re.findall(
    '(\w+(?:\s{1}\w+)*)[\s\S]+?(\d+\,\d{2})\n',
    content
)

for i, article in enumerate(articles, start=1):
    print(f'{i}) {article} \n')
```

El cual muestra la siguiente salida:

```
1) ('ACEITE OLIVA 750ML', '3,59') 

2) ('BIPACK KAS LIMÓN', '4,20') 

3) ('BIPACK KAS NARANJA', '9,00') 

4) ('CAVA CASTELL LLAC', '2,50') 

5) ('FAIRY REGULAR 1', '9,16') 

6) ('AGUJA CABO PEÑAS', '1,77') 

7) ('GALLETA MARIA DORADA', '1,98') 

8) ('NUEZ MONDADA CARRE', '2,26') 

9) ('CHORIZO DULCE CARR', '1,99') 

10) ('MORCILLA DE ARROZ', '1,39') 

11) ('OBLEAS EMPANADILLA', '2,67') 

12) ('YOGUR NATURAL 8 X125', '0,90') 

13) ('QUESO RESERVA 1', '3,48') 

14) ('ALMEJA MARINERA 500G', '7,99') 

15) ('ALMEJA MARINERA 500G', '7,99')
```